# Webpack error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/path/to/file.png'"

Tags: webpack

Look at the following *_url.scss* file I have:

```
$host-name: 'https://my-dev-host.com';

$icon-arrow-up-down: $host-name + '/folder/img/upDownArrows.png';
```

Webpack can compile with the file above and works perfectly.

However, it poses a question to a webpack newbie like me: it doesn't make sense to update the variable `$host-name` and compile the files for every environment I have. Good sense tells me that I would be able to serve files from root, like this:

```
//$host-name: ''; --no more needed

$icon-arrow-up-down: '/folder/img/upDownArrows.png';
```

But when I do this, webpack compiler throws the following error:
"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/folder/img/upDownArrows.png'"

I really think this should be related with some missing config, but I was not able to figure out which.
Also, is not an option to serve the .png file from within the project.

Can you help me out?

My webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const package = require('./package.json');
const {
    CleanWebpackPlugin
} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production ';

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app.js'),
        styleguide: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styleguide/scripts.js'),
        backoffice: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/backoffice/scripts.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: outputPath,
        publicPath: '/dist/',
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [`${outputPath}/*.hot-update.*`],
            dangerouslyAllowCleanPatternsOutsideProject: true,
            dry: false,
        }),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            banner: `[base] || Version: ${package.version} || Generated: ${new Date()}`,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            fs: false,
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 2,
                            sourceMap: !isProduction,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: !isProduction,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: !isProduction,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
    stats: {
        errorDetails: true,
    },
};
```

If you need more information, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's sorted out.

I updated the webpack.commom.js rules for css-loader so that it ignores url's.

```
[...]
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      url: false,
      importLoaders: 2,
      sourceMap: !isProduction,
    },
},
[...]
```

No more about the `url` option here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url